# better way for string comparison

Tags: c, string, strncmp

I have a JSON parser that sends a callback for every parsed key-value pair. I then use `strncmp` with statically allocated strings in my program to check if the field matches any of the fields I am interested in. I have now ended up with a dozen of `strncmp` in `if-else` statements:

```
if (strncmp(input, "apple", sizeof("apple")-1) == 0) 
    {// do something}
else if (strncmp(input, "banana", sizeof("banana")-1) == 0) 
    {// do something}
```

I'm not sure if this is an optimal/maintainable way of getting the job done. Is there a better way to do it? I already precompute the string lengths at compile time.

Comment: Why do you not use `strcmp`? Then you wouldn’t have to specify the length.

Comment: Are you aware that if `input` is `"apple or maybe not"` it will match the first condition?

Comment: @BertrandMarron yeah, I guess the string could be "applebanana" and the condition may still be true. Per mkrieger1 suggestion, it is a better idea to use strcmp?

Comment: How many fields are you interested in? 10?, 50? 100? 1000? For larger values, it's worth doing a hash and linked lists (or RB tree). For small: `char *table[] = { "apple", "banana", "cherry", NULL }; for (int i = 0;  table[i] != NULL;  ++i) { if (strcmp(buf,table[i]) == 0) { /*something*/ ; break }}`

Comment: @CraigEstey under 50 items. Thank you for the suggestion

Comment: Note that your comparisons will accept `”apple-strudel”` and `banana split”` as valid inputs.

Comment: If the list is predetermined/fixed (i.e. constant) and known at compile time, define the `table` as I suggested above (i.e. sorted). Do the linear search and measure performance. If slow, use a binary search. The usual breakover point to use binary search instead of linear is approximately 10 elements

Comment: @JonathanLeffler yes I understand, thank you for pointing it out. For this toy example, I should have used strcmp.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could define an array of static strings:

```
const char *field_names[] = {
    "apple",
    "banana",
    NULL
};
```

And then loop over the array, looking if the string matches one on the elements of the array:

```
for (int i = 0; field_names[i] != NULL; i++) {
    if (!strcmp(input, field_names[i]))
        // Do things
}
```

If you need to limit the size of the comparison, you could have an array a structures combining the name string + the size.

And if you need to do a different action for each one, you could include a function pointer in the structure to indicate what to do.

Comment: You could also define an array with function pointers (e.g.: `struct s_op { const char *fruit; void (*func)(void); };`).

Answer (score 0):

Depends on the size of your set. For large amount of long patterns, your O(MN) lookup is surely not optimal.

You can store them in a hash set (O(M) on average), or in a trie. You can even hardcode one on your own, if you've got a really fixed set of patterns from the Delphic Oracle and first letters are distributed more or less uniformly among patterns:

```c
switch(input[0]) {
case 'a': // check that it's an "apple"
          break;
}
```